# What does 'ϵx -minimal element' mean?

Tags: set-theory

It is from chapter 1 of *Set Theory* by Thomas Jech.I just don't know what this statement stands for.

Comment: More context would be welcome, but the text says in exercise 1.6:  "$t$ is $\in$-minimal in $z$ if there is no $s \in z$ such that $s \in t$".  This looks like a definition to me.

Comment: See page 14: "$t$ is $\in$-minimal in $z$ if there is no $s \in z$ such
that $s \in t$."